How to remove duplicates based on column1 and conditions in column3?
I'm trying to remove duplicates from a large csv file, based con values in column 1, but considering this:
Column 3 could be empty or have multiple values separated by :::
If there are more than one repeated value in column1, keep the record that has maximun number of elements inside the column 3.
Remove the - between numbers in column3 in case it exists.
My input is:
H1,H2,H3,H4
a,2,8005:::+2287:::3426,2
b,4,1111:::+15-00:::01354,1
b,4,1111:::+1500,1
c,4,2208:::+6583,9
d,5,7761:::+993733:::+53426,4
d,5,7761:::+993-733:::+53-426:::87425,4
d,5,7761:::53-426,4

The output I'm trying to get is:
H1,H2,H3,H4
a,2,8005:::+2287:::3426,2
b,4,1111:::+1500:::01354,1
c,4,2208:::+6583,9
d,5,7761:::+993733:::+53426:::87425,4

My current script only removes duplicates without the other considerations, since I'm don't how to mix both scripts and how to add the
condition to keep the record that has more elements in column 3.
awk -F, '{ gsub(/-/,"", $3); print } ' input.csv > input_without_hyphen.csv
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '!a[$1]++' input_without_hyphen.csv > output.csv

Thanks for any help.

what if two rows (with the same value in 1st column) have the same number of elements in the 3rd column

Hi markp, if 2 rows are exactly the same in all their columns, simply remove and keep one. The condition for column3 is when there are records that have all columns value equal but the difference is in number of elements within column3, in that case select the record with more elements in column3. The - are hyphen and don´t represent negative numbers since there are telephone numbers.

my question was aimed at what happens if two rows (exactly the same) have the same number of elements in column 3?

If 2 or more rows are exactly the same, having same elements in colum3 just keep one of them.

Assumptions:

the comma only shows up as a delimiter (ie, we don't have to worry about a comma showing up in the actual data)
if 2 rows are exactly the same and have the same number of elements in the 3rd column then we keep the first one we process
input order is to be maintained

One awk idea:
awk '
BEGIN  { FS = OFS = "," }

FNR==1 { print; next }              # print header as is

NF!=4  { next }                     # skip lines that do not have 4 comma-delimited fields

       { key = $1                   # define key for this row
         if (! (key in counts))     # if we have not seen this key before then ...
            order[++ordnum] = key   # associate the key with the next ordering number

         gsub(/-/,"",$3)            # remove all hyphens from 3rd column

         n = split($3,a,/:::/)      # split 3rd column on ":::" delimiter, store results in array a[]; "n" == number of elements in array

         if (n > counts[key]) {     # if the number of elements (in 3rd column) is more than the previous count (for a row with the same key) then ...
            counts[key] = n         # save the new count and ...
            rows[key]   = $0        # save the current row
         }
       }

END    { for (i=1; i<=ordnum; i++)  # iterate through our ordering numbers and ...
            print rows[order[i]]    # print the associated row to stdout
       }
' input.csv

This generates:
H1,H2,H3,H4
a,2,8005:::+2287:::3426,2
b,4,1111:::+1500:::01354,1
c,4,2208:::+6583,9
d,5,7761:::+993733:::+53426:::87425,4

NOTE: while the data came out in the same order as OP's expected output, ordering isn't always guaranteed; if the row order is important then we would need to add more code

Thanks for your solution, it seems to work fine. If possible would be better output in same order. Since the actual file it has thousands of records and is not easy visually check, is there a way to confirm that only duplicates elements were deleted? for example output unique records in output1 and the deleted in output2. If it is too much code is fine with this.

I can look at adding some code to maintain the order (as read); as for the 2nd requirement (2 sets of output), that changes the nature of the original question and I'd suggest you ask a new question

@RasecMalkic answer updated to maintain the input order

Thanks so much Mark, is only to confirm nothing else was deleted. Doesn't matter, your solution works correct with sample and seems to look fine with actual data. I'll check manually

not sure why but the second solution generates several blank lines.

@RasecMalkic the only thing I can think of is that you may have some blank lines, or lines with just white space; adding a few such lines to my sample data file will also generate 'blank lines'; I've updated the code (NF!=4 { next }) to skip such lines; if that doesn't address the issue then you'll need to track down the problematic rows to see what's different about them

Hi @markp-fuso, I see the actual data has empty lines. I didn´t know since if a very large file. Thanks again for your help
